# Como podría aplicar el orden Natural en este ejercicio? C# Web Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estoy teniendo un problema con este ejercicio de Web Form, en el mismo tengo 10 textbox y un botón que ordena de manera ascendente, los 10 txtbox están separados en 5 que son los que reciben la información y 5 donde se deposita de manera ordenada. Como se ve en la imagen los valores son alfanuméricos y los ordena de esta manera, pero tengo que usar la manera natural para ordenarlos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que estoy usando, si pudieran darme una ayuda para aplicar esa manera para ordenar los resultados sería de ayuda. Gracias

```
TextBox[] textBox = new TextBox[] { TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5 };
        string[] textBox1 = new string[] { TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text };
        TextBox[] textBox2 = new TextBox[] { TextBox6, TextBox7, TextBox8, TextBox9, TextBox10 };

        string k;//Variable que recibe un valor

        // Aplico Método Burbuja para ordenar los valores ingresados de manera ascendente.
        for (int x = 0; x < textBox.Length; x++)
        {
            if (textBox[x].Text == "")
            {
                Label1.Text = "Los 5 TextBox son requeridos.";
                Label1.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {   
                //Recorro los 5 TextBoxs de arriba.
                for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Length; i++)
                {
                    //Aplico Método Burbuja para ordenar los valores.
                    for (int b = 0; b < textBox1.Length - 1; b++)
                    {
                        //Busco en el primer caracter para realizar la comparación.
                      string box = textBox1[b].Substring(0);
                        //Comparo el primer for con el segundo en la posicion 1 y agrego el substring.
                        if (textBox1[i].CompareTo(textBox1[b + 1]) > 0 && textBox1[i].Equals(box))
                        {
                            //k obtiene el valor de b
                            k = textBox1[b];
                            textBox1[b] = textBox1[b + 1];
                            textBox1[b + 1] = k;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Length; i++)
            {
                //Coloco los valores ordenados en los 5 textbox que están abajo del botón.
                textBox2[i].Text = textBox1[i].ToString();
            }
```

[image: Esta es la forma esperada como orden natural]
Este es el resultado esperado.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que seria ordenar de manera natural?

Comment: Ya edite el post, gracias!

Comment: Tienes 5 `textbox`  en donde se colocan los datos de origen y cinco `textbox` donde el programa colocará los datos ordenados, sin embargo en tu código solo haces referencia a `textBox1` y `textBox2`, dudo mucho que con solo ese tramo de código, puedas ordenar los datos, te recomiendo comenzar por mostrar el código, del evento `click` del botón que  muestra el texto "Mover", que es donde debe iniciarse todo el proceso por el cual se produce la ordenación de los datos.

Comment: Ya edite el código, espero que ahora sea entendible.